# If sheet name equals to a cell from a named range then

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a tab for a number of different people, which has their own data in it. However, the macros which work on these tabs use "If sheet name Then", but it's not dynamic. Is there a way to make it dynamic based on a named range?

i.e. the range would be a list of names like John, Ben, Steve etc. and the macro would search if the sheet name is equal to one of the names in that range. Here's a piece of the current code:

```
Sub apply_exclusion_format()

Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Range
On Error Resume Next

For Each sht In Worksheets
        Set r = sht.Cells.Range("A:AY")
        If sht.Name <> "MASTER" And sht.Name <> "Exclusions" _
        And sht.Name <> "Bands" And sht.Name <> "Matrix" _
        And sht.Name <> "Macros" Then
            sht.Select
            r.Select
```

Rather than excluding sheets by using "sht.Name <>" I want to include sheets whose name falls within a range saved on a sheet somewhere.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what should happen?   What happens if the the sheet name is `John`?  What if it's `Ben`?

Comment: Depending on the sheet name, that sheet gets selected and then formatted

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next

For Each sht In Worksheets

 Thisworkbook.Worksheets("sheetwhererangeis").Range("A1:A5").Find sht.name
```

Just define your range and look for sht.name etc lather, rinse and repeat

Comment: where exactly do I add that?

Comment: @gourdblessamerica Its hard to guess without more code but I think this might help. The point was more to illustrate how to check for a value in a range with .Find

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - e.g. to check whether a sheet is in a list of "excluded" sheet names -

```
Function IsExcludedSheet(sName)
    IsExcludedSheet = Not IsError(Application.Match(sName, Range("EXCLUDED"), 0))
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Sub apply_exclusion_format()

Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Range
On Error Resume Next '<<< do you really need this?

For Each sht In Worksheets
        Set r = sht.Cells.Range("A:AY")
        If Not IsExcluded(sht.Name) Then '<<< call the function here
            sht.Select
            r.Select
```

Comment: how do I incorporate that into the existing macro? I don't want it to be a function, just a step in the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several innovative methods in VBA as solution to your problem. We can do the sheet name search, a bit more dynamic in following ways.

Let's assume the name of range with sheet names is *rngSheetInclusions*.

**Method #1**: Using COUNTIF:

The COUNTIF function counts cells that meet supplied criteria, returning the number of occurrences found. If no cells meet criteria, COUNTIF returns zero. Any positive number means the value was found. This means you can use the greater than operator (>) to run a simple test on the result of COUNTIF to force a TRUE or FALSE result

```
Sub apply_exclusion_format()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Range
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        Set r = sht.Cells.Range("A:AY")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("rngSheetInclusions"),sht.Name) > 0 Then
            'Do whatever you want to
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Method #2**: As an alternative, you can use a formula that uses the MATCH function instead of COUNTIF. The MATCH function returns the position of a match (as a number) if found, and #N/A if not found. By wrapping MATCH inside ISNUMBER, the final result will be TRUE when MATCH finds a match and FALSE when MATCH returns #N/A. Here is the If statement to be used :

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Match(sht.Name, Range("rngSheetInclusions"), 0)) Then
```

**Method #3**: Using VBA's Find method: You can also replace the If statement in the for loop with the one below to achieve the desired result.

```
If Not Range("rngSheetInclusions").Find(What:=sht.Name, Lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it based on Doug Coats' suggestion. Instead of this:

```
Sub apply_exclusion_format()

Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Range
On Error Resume Next

For Each sht In Worksheets
        Set r = sht.Cells.Range("A:AY")
        If sht.Name <> "MASTER" And sht.Name <> "Exclusions" _
        And sht.Name <> "Bands" And sht.Name <> "Matrix" _
        And sht.Name <> "Macros" Then
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, rFound As Range
On Error Resume Next

For Each sht In Sheets
Set rFound = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ranges").Range("Reviewer_sheet_names").Find(sht.Name)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
```

I create a named range on the sheet "Ranges" which contains the sheets that the macros act upon. Again, it's not dynamic, but it is a heck of a lot easier to edit. Thanks Doug!